# How to get pre-defined vibration patterns?

Tags: android, android-source, android-vibration

I'm trying to make the device vibrate in a pre-defined pattern, which is defined in the `VibrationEffect` class, with patterns like `EFFECT_CLICK`, `EFFECT_POP`, and others. I noticed that they are all annotated by `@hide`, It seems like there's no public method for me to get these patterns, `VibrationEffect.get()` doesn't work.

So how should I get such patterns? Or is it not possible at all? I also tried to dig into the Android source code to find these patterns, I'm particularly interested in the pre-defined Ringtone vibration patterns, but I can't seem to find them, all I can find is the interface package that defines vibration patterns. Can someone point me the right way if I'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain any pattern using `VibrationEffect.createPredefined(int)`, example:

```
val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as? Vibrator
val effect: VibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK)
vibrator?.vibrate(effect)
```

Note that `VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK` can be replaced with other values that are mentioned in [AOSP reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect#EFFECT_CLICK). Minimal required API is 29 (Android 10).

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to recreate these vibration patterns, so I did some trial and error to get these numbers. They are as close to what I felt was right.

```
        val singleClickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 10)
        val singleClickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 180)

        val doubleClickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 10, 160, 10)
        val doubleClickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 255, 0, 255)

        val heavyClickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 13)
        val heavyClickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 255)

        val tickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 5)
        val tickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 50)
```

Using them like this:

```
vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createWaveform(tickPattern, tickAmplitude, -1)
vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect);
```

You can try them out yourself by looping through the predefined ones and these ones.